What to do with philosophical questions that are considered too vague or subjective?
Philosophical questions that lack the necessary rigor and analytical framework are traditionally left to religious scholars to deal with. But nowadays, it is often not an option for a lot of people. They would not accept an answer from the Church. They expect scientifically strong answers.
Then who, and how should be addressing these generic but important philosophical questions?

Philosophy primarily focuses on analyzing concepts and ideas, so
questions that rely heavily on personal opinions or subjective
experiences might not be considered suitable for philosophical
investigation
https://www.encyclopedia.com/education/applied-and-social-sciences-magazines/philosophical-questions-their-nature-and-function#:~:text=Because%20the%20facts%20do%20not,be%20opposed%20by%20contrasting%20views.
A philosophical question often doesn't have a clear, straightforward
answer. They are questions that usually require deep thought and
sometimes don't have answers. Philosophical questions typically
involve human nature, the origins of the universe, morality, ethics,
and the afterlife.
https://www.scienceofpeople.com/philosophical-questions/#:~:text=A%20philosophical%20question%20often%20doesn,%2C%20ethics%2C%20and%20the%20afterlife.

Examples of philosophical questions:
What is the difference between good and bad people?
Are some people more important than others?
What is wisdom?
Can we choose our emotions, or do they happen to us?
What is love?
What is culture?
What is success?
What happens after death?
Is luck a real thing?
Does life have meaning? If so, what is the meaning of life?
Is there absolute truth?
Are pain and beauty interconnected?
Can pain be a good thing?
Why do people enjoy looking at art?

Nonduality unasks basically all of these.

From my pov this is a v good question. But from the pov of phil-SE this is more suitable for meta than for main (if at all it's tolerated). Sad? Maybe... But true

Same here. I was thinking about philosophy.meta first.

@Rushi - My closed questions sometimes trigger clever follow-ups. So, not everything is lost. :)

There may not be scientifically strong answers to all of these. Or there may not yet be such answers. Or they may be answers in the sciences rather than in abstract philosophy. Or they may be only answerable by individual reflection and deciding what they mean to you rather than relying upon someone else's analysis. It is always easier to generate questions than to pick out the answers for them. (I am not currently voting to close, but I would argue that this deserves to be closed as unfocused, trying to ask too many questions at once where there may be no common answer. Or even principle.)

We've also seen answers go by for some of them. For example, our consensus here was that there may be absolute truths, but that there are very few that humans can confidently recognize as such; reality is fuzzy, fractal, and in general more complicated than we wish it was.  So those, if broken out, would be closed as duplicates.

@keshlam - It takes time for people to process that philosophical questions cannot be answered in Philosophy meta.

It's not even possible for philosophers to give "scientifically strong answers".  Philosophers don't do science; that's why they're philosophers, not scientists.

What I suggest doing with them is taking them elsewhere, to a site that is less focused on answerable questions. Stack Exchange is not the right place for all questions; by design, it is explicitly focused on questions that have a relatively small number of clear, relatively short, actionable answers.

I hope you realize that your answer would make sense for Philosophy meta old-timers. But for new members and for the reading public, it would be confusing.

"answerable questions" - this by itself is a very difficult philosophical dilemma.

Well, it makes sense for stack exchange old -timers. An expanded essay on the topic belongs elsewhere.

And if there is no God, then why does religion have to answer questions that are too general for philosophy?

Answerable questions: this is why the stack is supposed to be about discussing philosophy rather than doing philosophy. We aren't going to resolve any of the great questions here. What we can do is point people in the direction of answers and suggest which paths are unlikely to be productive.

First, I'm agnostic, so I don't know if there is a god. However, if there is one then it is studied by the branch we call religious philosophy and/or history of religions, and I would suggest that questions should be referred thereunto for the same reasons that I would suggest questions about demonstrable properties of matter should be referred to the branch of philosophy we call the sciences. If religion doesn't want to answer those questions, of course, that's its business... But in my experience it has little hesitation in doing so.

"What we can do is point people in the direction of answers" - This sounds promising. Can you give an example when an unanswerable philosophical question was pointed in the right direction?

We are definitely getting into meta territory here, but we have seen questions answered with citations of specific philosophers or schools of philosophy that have investigated those areas. Arguably, those are the answers that this stack was originally designed for.

Philosophy starts with Socrates answering this in Republic (Symposium and elsewhere).
A brief redact of Plato/Platonism

This world is a shadow world.
The real world is the essence world — more typically called the "World of Forms"
Essences = {Gratitude, Compassion, Love. Truth, Beauty, (the) Good..}
The essence world is structured in 3 tiers:

Gateway Tier — math.
By giving a field of non-empirical ie. non-shadow-world truth as a practice field.
(Also music — Pythagoras more or else equated the two)
The world proper
It's top element — the Good in Republic,  Beauty In Symposium


Truth is the lowest element of the world proper.
The proper domain of philosophy is the lowest element — Truth — because the Good has no being, though being arises from the Good.

Wittgenstein
The closing chord of the Tractatus can be seen as the conspective summary of the above:

Whereof we cannot speak we must be silent

 2. Whereof we can speak — the True
 3. Whereof we can't — the Good
 1. The form of the Tractatus — math
Christianity
"God" and "Good" are uncannily close.
And in a slew of unrelated languages

I guess the idea that a religious scholar can answer the questions that philosophers cannot would be alien to Socrates.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance It's funny you say that. Socrates was killed for alleged impiety. He cheerily cheekily and stoutly defended himself by referring to the fact that God (Apollo) called him the wisest of the wise. Beyond the cheek it signifies that  Socrates considered himself religious. Of course this is a bit anachronistic because "religion" is a post Christian ontic category

@TheMatrixEquation-balance Important to remember: If we agree that the word religion has any meaning whatever, we are Christian. It's a minor quibble of window dressing after thar whether we claim to be religious, irreligious, non-religious, anti-religious. If we acquiesce to the ontic 'religion' we've acquiesced to Christian framing. Longer version. A Hindu/Buddhist/Jain/Sikh would say dharma — a quite different framing

"Dharma refers to behaviors that are in accordance with Ṛta, or "order and custom". It can also mean duties, rights, laws, conduct, virtues, and the "right way of living". The word dharma comes from a Sanskrit root word that means "to uphold or sustain""

@TheMatrixEquation-balance rita is even more hard to translate than dharma! My preferred rendering: dharma: internal law, karma: external law,; rita: cosmic law. One could describe the whole project of Hinduism as being about how to sit oneself rightly on this law-tripod
